# R: create a function in tidyverse

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I have some fake data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
                 var1 = sample(c(0,1), size = 20, replace = T),
                 var2 = round(runif(20, min = 0, max = 100),0),
                 var3 = round(runif(20, min = 0, max = 100),0),
                 var4 = round(rnorm(20, mean = 50, sd = 20)),
                 var5 = sample(c(1:19, NA), size=20))
```

Then, I would like to do some checks on these data:. The IDs of the rows that have errors and an error message should be put in a data.frame `errors`. I would like to call the function using the pipe-operator %>%

```r
### Different checks

# There should be no missing values in var5
df %>% filter(is.na(var5)) %>% add_errors("There are NAs in var5")

# var3 should be greater than var4
df %>% filter(var3 < var4) %>% add_errors("var3 is smaller than var4")

# ... etc.
```

Then I have to define the function `add_errors()`:

```r
### Define function

errors <- data.frame(id = numeric(), errormessage = character())

add_errors <- function(dat, error){
    errors <<- add_case(errors, id = dat[['id']], errormessage = error)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does something similar to what you are asking. I tried doing it without passing the errors data frame as an argument, but it doesn't end up changing the errors variable outside of the function.

```
errors=data.frame(id=numeric(), errormessage=character())
add_errors=function(df, errormessage) {
    return(bind_rows(errors, data.frame(id=df$id, errormessage=errormessage)))
}
errors=df %>% filter(is.na(var5)) %>% add_errors("There are NAs in var5") 
errors=df %>% filter(var3 > var4) %>% add_errors("var3 is smaller than var4")
```

Output:

```
> print(errors)
  id              errormessage
1  3     There are NAs in var5
2  2 var3 is smaller than var4
3  3 var3 is smaller than var4
4  7 var3 is smaller than var4
5  8 var3 is smaller than var4
6  9 var3 is smaller than var4
7 12 var3 is smaller than var4
8 16 var3 is smaller than var4
9 18 var3 is smaller than var4
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice! Unfortunately, I need all the different error message in one data.frame at the end, so the function needs to access the data.frame defined outside the function I guess.

Answer (score 1):

We could either print the error message on the console

```
add_errors <- function(dat, error) {
    glue::glue("{error} at id: {toString(dat[['id']])}")
   }
```

-testing

```
df %>%
    filter(is.na(var5)) %>% 
    add_errors("There are NAs in var5")
#There are NAs in var5 at id: 6

df %>%
   filter(var3 < var4) %>%
   add_errors("var3 is smaller than var4")
#var3 is smaller than var4 at id: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 15, 16, 17, 20
```

---

Or return a tibble/data.frame with error message as output

```
add_errors <- function(dat, error) {
     tibble(id = dat[['id']], errormessage = error)
    }
    
df %>%
     filter(is.na(var5)) %>% 
     add_errors("There are NAs in var5")
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#     id errormessage         
#  <int> <chr>                
#1     6 There are NAs in var5
```

---

An option is to make use of `logger` which would make it more flexible to add error, warning, info etc. along with the timestamp

```
#remotes::install_github('daroczig/logger')
library(logger)
log_layout(layout_glue_colors)
t <- tempfile()
log_appender(appender_file(t))
log_info('Script starting up...')

df %>%
     filter(is.na(var5)) %>%
    {log_error('There are NAs in var5')}
    
df %>%
   filter(var3 < var4) %>%
   {log_error("var3 is smaller than var4")}
cat(readLines(t), sep="\n")
#INFO [2021-02-28 14:28:42] Script starting up...
#ERROR [2021-02-28 14:28:42] There are NAs in var5
#ERROR [2021-02-28 14:28:43] var3 is smaller than var4

unlink(t)
```

The `t` is a temporary file, which can also be written into a custom destination folder

Comment: At the end I need a data.frame having two columns: 1. the IDs of the cases that contain errors, 2. the error message itself

Comment: @D.Studer Please see the updated solution

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Just one more thing: All the error messages should written in the same data.frame.

Comment: @D.Studer I updated with a more general functionality with `logger`

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is about creating a custom function to check for errors. But there is a nice package called {pointblank} which is exactly made for this kind of task.

Instead of setting up a `data.frame` called `error`, we can set up an so called "agent" and "interrogate" it to get a nice report. There are several alternative workflows to check for errors which are described on [the package's website](https://rich-iannone.github.io/pointblank/articles/validation_workflows.html). Below is one possible way to use the package on your problem.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(pointblank)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:20,
                 var1 = sample(c(0,1), size = 20, replace = T),
                 var2 = round(runif(20, min = 0, max = 100),0),
                 var3 = round(runif(20, min = 0, max = 100),0),
                 var4 = round(rnorm(20, mean = 50, sd = 20)),
                 var5 = sample(c(1:19, NA), size=20))
agent <- df %>%
  create_agent(
    label = "My error checks",
    actions = action_levels(stop_at = 1)
  ) %>%
  col_vals_not_null(var5) %>% 
  col_vals_not_in_set(
    vars(var3_lt_4),
    preconditions = ~ . %>% dplyr::mutate(var3_lt_4 = var3 > var4),
    set = FALSE) %>% 
  interrogate()
  
agent
```